# How to display currently logged in user's information from oracle database to jsp form

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a login form in JSP. All the login information I'm storing in Oracle database.

For new users they need to register to login. 
But for the users those who have accounts, as they logs in they will have the option called "Account Setting" where they can edit their basic information.

When user clicks on that link, his account information should be displayed.
But I'm not able to retrieve currently logged in user's information from database.

Here is my JSP code to check whether user's account exists or not:

```
 <%  

try 

{

     String user=request.getParameter("username");

     String pass=request.getParameter("password");

     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     Connection 

  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","manager");
  Statement st=con.createStatement();

 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from student where
 username='"+user+"' and 

 password='"+pass+"'");

  int count=0;
        while(rs.next())
       {
           count++;
       }

           if(count>0)
            {
             out.println("welcome "+user);
            }
           else
             {
               response.sendRedirect("studentlogin.jsp");
             } 

 }
   catch(Exception e) 
{  
 out.println(e); 
} 

 %>

    <a href="settings_std.jsp">Account Setting</a>
```

If the user is valid then he can see the option "Account setting". i.e.

```
 <%

    String username=request.getParameter("username");

      Connection con=null;

  try 

{

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system",
 "manager");    

Statement
st=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from from student where
 username='"+username+"'");


  if(rs.next())

 {

 %>

         <h3>Your Account Information</h3>

        <table>

<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" value="          <%=rs.getString("name")%>"></td></tr>


<tr><td>Degree:</td><td><input type="text" name="degree" value="<%=rs.getString("degree")%>"></td></tr>


<tr><td>Semester:</td><td><input type="text" name="semester" value="<%=rs.getString("semester")%>"></td></tr>


<tr><td>Branch</td><td><input type="text" name="branch" value="<%=rs.getString("branch")%>"></td></tr>



<tr><td>Contact No:</td><td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="<%=rs.getString("mobile")%>"></td></tr>


<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"
 value="<%=rs.getString("email")%>"></td></tr>


<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" name="password"  value="<%=rs.getString("password")%>"></td></tr>

</table>



 <%

   }

 con.close();
   }

 %>
```

Hope somebody knows this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit your code. Don't use block comments (`>`) for code. Read the [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). If you want to get attention then please show some effort.

Comment: @user please format your code properly then we will see.

Comment: Do you have any exception, error message or whatsoever? What is not working, currently?

Comment: You need to fetch values from ResultSet and set into an Object. And access this Object in UI/JSP level. Please refactor your code..

Comment: As u people suggested i have formatted my code. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: I want to fetch currently logged in user's account information. But I'm not able to do that. In my code i'm using rs.next() which fetches the information of last stored user's information from database.

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution to my problem. To fetch values from database we can make use of JSP Sessions.

i.e.

```
<%
   String name = request.getParameter( "username" );
   session.setAttribute( "theName", name );
%>
```

In next page to retrieve the saved username

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from student where username='"+session.getAttribute("theName")+"'");
```

A session is an object associated with a visitor. Data can be put in the session and retrieved from it.

Anyhow thank you for trying guys.